# Expanding nested object using OData client v3

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I am encountering some issues, using Microsooft.Data.Services.Client in a .NET Framework project, and trying to expand objects of 2nd level.

Here is an example, having following data model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

If I'm using the .Execute() method, and provide a RequestUri like the following:
`"V3/Customer?$expand=Order,Order/Item"`
it will actually work, and do lazy loading on the sub-elements to include in my query.

If I'm using the DataServiceQuery like this (where context is an instance of DataServiceContext):

```
var q = context.Customers.Expand(x => x.Order).Expand(x => x.Order.Item);
```

This will load the Order object to the customer result, but NOT the Item of the order.

If I look on the query that the context will create, it is similar to the Uri use in the Execute.

How do I load nested elements (in this case 'Order/Item') using DataServiceContext with OData client V3?

Comment: Id and Description are properties (columns) of the Table Item.

Comment: @jdweng the issue is that I want to select Customer.Order.Item.Description for instance, but when using the OData client the Customer.Order.Item is NULL

Comment: Was data ever put into the Item?  If no rows of data was written to the datatable nothing will come out.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, the properties does have a value. As mentioned in the thread, if I use the .Execute<Customer>(...) with a Uri as parameter, then it works. But I do not want to rely on string/Uri constructions.

Comment: I usually use Select and SelectMany : var q = context.Customers.SelectMany(x => x.Order.Select(y => x.Item)).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately thats not an option is my case, as the Order is not a collection but a single instance of an object (please notice that the data model is OP is just a simplified example). .Expand work fine on the first nested object, but seems to fail when I want to load nested object og another nested object.

Comment: That is why your expand didn't work.  Try : var q = context.Customers.SelectMany(x => x.Order.Item)).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng The 'Customers' is type of DataServiceQuery<Customer>, which contains one instance of a Order element (not a IEnumerable<Order>), which means it is not possible to do .SelectMany(x => x.Order.Item) as select many function expect an IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use projections and set the MergeOption to OverwriteChanges in this case.

I.e.

```
using(var ctx = new DataServiceContext(...){MergeOption = OverwriteChanges})
{
    from c in ctx.Customers
    select new Customer
    {
        Order = new Order
        {
            Item = new Item
            {
                Id = c.Order.Item.Id,
                Description = c.Order.Item.Description
            }
        }

    }
}
```